# Background image increase size with scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the background image on a `div` change its scale as per the amount of page scrolled. Works well on desktop screens but on mobile screen, the BG image's height reduces and shrinks the image. This behaviour is apparent as I am trying to resize a sized `cover` image in `%` values. I have added a red `background-color` too to the div for better debugging. Any way to make it work flawlessly even on mob screens? The code is below as well as on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/khan360/pen/gOGbqjL).

**HTML:**

```
<main>
  <div class="section_1">
        <div class="welcome_message">            
            <div class="welcome_text">
                <p class="welcome">Welcome to</p>
                <h1>My</h1>
                <p class="tagline">DIRECTORY</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

**CSS:**

```
main{
min-height: 200vh;  
}

.section_1{
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 90vh;
        background: red url(https://images.pexels.com/photos/9467294/pexels-photo-9467294.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260) 40% 10%/cover no-repeat;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: flex-end;
        align-items: flex-end;
}

.section_1 .welcome_message{
            width: 80%;
            min-height: 100%;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: flex-end;
            align-items: flex-end;
            background: none;
            padding: 0 1rem 10rem 0;

            .welcome_text{    
                z-index: 3;
                // color: white;
                background-color: rgba(1, 55, 131, 0.5);
                border-bottom: 0.5rem solid white;
                padding: 1rem 2rem;
                border-end-start-radius: 2rem;
            }

            .welcome{
                color: white;
                font-weight: 400;
            }

            h1{
                font-size: 2rem;
                color: white;
                font-weight: 600;
                margin-block: -0.3em;
            }

            .tagline{
                color: white;
                font-weight: 400;
            }
  }
```

**JS:**

```
let bg = document.querySelector('body .section_1')

document.addEventListener('scroll', () => {        
  let x = window.pageYOffset
  bg.style.backgroundSize = (100 + x/10)+'% auto'
})
```

[image]

Comment: As for reference. [`background-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size). https://jsfiddle.net/z10sf74x/

Comment: @vee thanks but please check my edited OP.

Comment: About your `90vh`, I can't reproduce that.

Comment: @vee Could you check my Codepen [link](https://codepen.io/khan360/pen/gOGbqjL) please. Keep the Preview pane on either left/right to resize the pane and observe the background image's height reduce on mobile screen. I have added a red color to the 'div' along with the image so you can see that the div itself does not resize, only the bg image does.

This behaviour is apparent as I am trying to resize a `background-size:cover` image in %. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

you almost made it instead of using `auto` use the calculated width and set the height to `100%`

```
bg.style.backgroundSize = ''+(130 + x/10)+'% 100%'
```

[Codepen :)](https://codepen.io/abdennor/pen/qBPxbeB)

Comment: Looks good brother but I want to use it with custom `background-position` of `40% 10%`. Please check my edited OP.

Answer (score 1):

Because you scroll all the way top again, bg.style.backgroundSize = 'auto 130%', The value of bg.style.backgroundSize should null.